# Is a person allowed to wear new jewelery during the 9 days?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, nine-days, jewelry

Dumb question I know, but; does jewelery fall under the catagory of a garment, and as such is not allowed to be worn, if new, in the nine days?